# actual objects and its references in python

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused about actual object and its reference in python.Googled a lot but didn't get what I need.

Does object creation also returns a reference to that object? Why i'm asking this is because I'm able to use actual object with `.` delimiter to call its methods.We usually use reference of the object to call methods.An example might give a clear idea of what I'm asking.

`l = [2,4,1,3]` # 'l' is a reference to actual object.Right?

does the RHS part create the object and return a reference to that object which'll be assigned to LHS ?

Because I'm able to use both `list.sort()` and `[2,4,1,3].sort()` to sort the list. Is `[2,4,1,3]` an actual object or does it yield a reference along with creating an object?

Similar is the case with Classes.

`obj=SomeClass()` #obj is a reference to object created by SomeClass().

Does `SomeClass()` return a reference along with creating an object?

Because we can use both `obj.method1()` and `SomeClass().method1` to call methods.

Comment: Perhaps a [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12080644) of mine helps you understand this?

Comment: The following link discusses this, specifically how Python differs from other languages:
http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you reading [The Python Language Reference "Data Model"](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html).

In python, when you create an object, it's being allocated in heap. If you assign your object to some variable, you actually are *tagging* it. One object may have many tags. When object *looses* all tags it *may* be destroyed by python garbage collector. So, an answer to your question -- [1,2,3] *does not* return any references, but simply creates new object.

EDIT:

Actually, during

```
[1, 2, 3].sort()
```

There is a reference to [1, 2, 3] list, that stays in VM's stack. But, as said before, it's not returned. But during:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

This reference is copied from VM's stack to l.

Comment: So [1,2,3] is object.if a=[2,1,3],'a' is reference to the object [2,1,3]. Can you relate the analogy a.sort() vs [2,1,3].sort() ?

Comment: I've added some edits above. Both examples are the same, the difference comes in the way, we refer to the list: through *a* variable or by VM's itself, taking this reference from it's stack.

Comment: Its all making some sense now ,though i didn't grasp the whole thing.But very soon i'll. Thank you so much

Comment: You're always welcome. May be it's difficult for you to *grasp* it, 'courze you've got used to some other languages (like Java) and their implementations of Object manipulation. BTW, now we've been talking about cpython realization, but there many other ones (jython and so on), and each one may have it's own vision to this concept.