# Simple python code about double loop

Tags: python

I tested the following python code on Spyder IDE. Thinking it would output 2d array `q` as increasing number as 0..31 from `q[0][0]` to `q[3][7]`. But it actually returns q as:

```
[[24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]].
```

The code:

```
q=[[0]*8]*4 
for i in range(4): 
    for j in range(8): 
        q[i][j] = 8*i+j 
print q
```

Any idea of what's happening here? I debugged step by step. It shows the updates of every row will sync with all other rows, quite different from my experience of other programing languages.

Answer (score 4):

```
q=[somelist]*4
```

creates a list with four identical items, the list `somelist`. So, for example, `q[0]` and `q[1]` reference the same object.

Thus, in the nested for loop `q[i]` is referencing the same list regardless of the value of `i`.

To fix:

```
q = [[0]*8 for _ in range(4)]
```

The list comprehension evaluates `[0]*8` 4 distinct times, resulting in 4 distinct lists.

---

Here is a quick demonstration of this pitfall:

```
In [14]: q=[[0]*8]*4
```

You might think you are updating only the first element in the second row:

```
In [15]: q[1][0] = 100
```

But you really end up altering the first element in *every* row:

```
In [16]: q
Out[16]: 
[[100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: How about j in this case? Is it supposed to be all q[i][0] and q[i][1] reference the same object as well?

Comment: @user1640608 when you are using primitives (integer, etc), the reference isn't repeated.

Comment: Lists are mutable, integers are not. So if `q[0]` and `q[1]` point to the same list, then `q[0][j] = 100` will modify `q[1][j]` as well. Although `[0]*8` does create a list with 8 references to the same integer, it does not cause a problem because we aren't mutating the integers (an impossibility); we only alter the list's reference to point at other values.

Comment: @user1640608: see this old answer of mine: [Python list doesn't reflect variable change, new to python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/12080644#12080644); perhaps it'll help you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

As explained the problem is caused due to `*` operation on lists, which create more references to the same object. What you should do is to use append:

```
q=[]
for i in range(4): 
    q.append([])
    for j in range(8): 
        q[i].append(8*i+j)
print q
```

> > [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23], [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like `l = [x]*8` you are actually creating 8 references to the same `list`, not 8 copies.

To actually get 8 copies, you have to use `l = [[x] for i in xrange(8)]`

```
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> l=[x]*8
>>> l
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
>>> l[0][0]=10
>>> l
[[10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3], [10, 2, 3]]
>>> l = [ [x] for i in xrange(8)]
>>> l
[[[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]]]
>>> l[0][0] = 1
>>> l
[[1], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]], [[10, 2, 3]]]
```

Comment: Not correct because what you are saying is `[0]*8` will create repeated references, which it will not, only something like `[[0]]*8` will do such a thing because the outer `[]` will contain a reference and not a primitive.