# changing an item in a list of lists

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple python code about double loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236148/simple-python-code-about-double-loop)

I'm stuck with the well known problem of changing 1 item in a list of lists. I need to use a fixed size list of list.

If I use:

```
In [21]: a=[[2]*2]*3

In [22]: a
Out[22]: [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]

In [23]: a[0][0]=1

In [24]: a
Out[24]: [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

But if I define the list of list in the following way, it works:

```
In [26]: a = [
   ....: [2,2],
   ....: [2,2],
   ....: [2,2],
   ....: ]

In [27]: a   
Out[27]: [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]

In [28]: a[0][0]=1

In [29]: a
Out[29]: [[1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

To me line 22 and 27 looks identical. So which is the difference?

Can someone explain me how to go around this problem and, in particular, how to change a code that change a single item of a list of list? If this is not possible, any suggestion to move to a different data structure allowing that?
thanks

Comment: sorry - but I was going to show how two different ways to generate an array brings to the same output. And however I understand there is NO WAY to sort out the system with a fixed size list of lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a fundamental difference in the 2 ways you defined the matrix in both code samples. In the first (line 21) when you multiply the outer list by 3 you actually multiply the references to the inner list.

Here's a parameterized example:

```
a = [2,2]
b = [a] * 3
b => [a, a, a] => [[2,2], [2,2], [2,2]]
```

As you can see the numerical representation of `b` is what you would expect, but it actually contains 3 references to `a`. So if you change either of the inner lists, they all change, because they are actually the same list.

Instead of multiplication you need to clone the lists doing something like this

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

or

```
new_list = list(old_list)
```

In the case of nested lists, this can be done using loops.

Comment: thanks, but how to write something that works and actually change only the item I need to change? I'm quite a newbie (at least in the use of list..).

Comment: @user1640950 use this `a=[[2]*2 for _ in range(3)]`

Comment: @user1640950 thank us by accepting any of the answers. see [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)