# python - class mutability

Tags: python, class, mutability

I got the code below from an exam and I don't understand why the first time when you make `f2 = f1`, doing `f1.set()` changes `f2` but after that when you set `f1 = Foo("Nine", "Ten")` doesn't change `f2` at all. If anyone knows why please explain it to me. Thank you so much!

Code:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, x=1, y=2, z=3):
        self.nums = [x, y, z]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nums)

    def set(self, x):
        self.nums = x

f1 = Foo()
f2 = Foo("One", "Two")

f2 = f1
f1.set(["Four", "Five", "Six"])
print f1
print f2

f1 = Foo("Nine", "Ten")
print f1
print f2

f1.set(["Eleven", "Twelve"])
print f1
print f2
```

Outcome:

```
['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
['Nine', 'Ten', 3]
['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
['Eleven', 'Twelve']
['Four', 'Five', 'Six']
```

Comment: are you taking the exam right now?

Comment: Does this old answer of mine help? [Python list doesn't reflect variable change, new to python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/12080644#12080644)

Comment: Try running this code through the visualizer at [Python Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com).

Answer (score 5):

```
f2 = f1
```

After this statement both `f1` and `f2` are references to the *same* instance of `Foo`. Therefore, a change in one will effect the other.

```
f1 = Foo("Nine", "Ten")
```

After this, `f1` is assigned to a *new* `Foo` instance so `f1` and `f2` are no longer connected in any way - so a change in one will *not* effect the other.