# Why does Python treat lists and integers differently in Class namespace?

Tags: python, class, namespaces

These two class definitions are structured identically, except in the weird() class definition the attribute 'd' is a list, and in the normal() class definition its an int. I dont understand why the weird() class results in self.d = d, while this is not the case with the class normal().  Why does Python treat int and list differently in this situation?

```
class weird:
    def __init__(self):
        d = [1,2,3]
        self.d = d
        for x in range(3):
            d[x] = 10+x 
        print "d =", d
        print "self.d =", self.d

class normal:
    def __init__(self):
        d = 1
        self.d = d
        d = 11
        print "d =", d
        print "self.d =", self.d
```

And when I run the code, I get

```
>>> a=weird()
d = [10, 11, 12]
self.d = [10, 11, 12]
>>> b=normal()
d = 11
self.d = 1
```

Comment: "in the weird() class definition the attribute 'd' is an int, and in the normal() class definition its a list." This is the reverse of true.

Comment: That's not the only difference either. One does an variable assignment, while the other does a number of sequence item assignments.

Comment: Yup, I had that backwards.  I know the other does a number of assignments, but basically "I changed the value of d".  Martijn cleared it up for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are confusing assignment with mutation of an object.

In one method, you assigned new values to `d`, changing what it points to:

```
d = 11
```

but in the other method you changed values *contained* in `d`:

```
d[x] = 10 + x
```

Note the `[x]` there; you are, in essence, telling python to do this:

```
d.__setitem__(x, 10 + x)
```

The value of the variable `d`, which points to a list, is never changed. The values in the list referred to by `d`, do change.

Take a look at this previous answer of mine, which goes into more detail as to what the difference is between these two statements: [Python list doesn't reflect variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644).

Comment: Thanks Martijn.  This answers it for me.

Answer (score 2):

**In fact, the language is perfectly consistent here. You are observing two different behaviours because you are performing two fundamentally different operations.**

The first two lines of `__init__` are consistent in both classes (except for the different types of `d`):

```
class WeirdOrNormal:
    def __init__(self):
        d = ... # 1 or [1, 2, 3]
        self.d = d
```

At this point, both `d` and `self.d` refer to the same object.

However, after that, the two classes diverge:

1. `weird` modifies the object through the reference:

   ```
   for x in range(3):
       d[x] = 10+x
   ```

   Since both `d` and `self.d` refer to the same object, the change can be observed through both.
2. `normal` rebinds `d` to point somewhere other than `self.d`:

   ```
   d = 11
   ```

   By doing this, you've broken the link between `d` and `self.d`. They are now completely independent.

If you were to change `weird` to also rebind the reference, just like `normal` does, you'd see the two classes behave consistently with one another:

```
class notweird:
    def __init__(self):
        d = [1,2,3]
        self.d = d
        d = [10+x for x in self.d]
        print "d =", d
        print "self.d =", self.d

a = notweird()
```

This prints

```
d = [11, 12, 13]
self.d = [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

For docs:

> Objects whose value can change are said to be mutable; objects whose
>   value is unchangeable once they are created are called immutable. (The
>   value of an immutable container object that contains a reference to a
>   mutable object can change when the latter’s value is changed; however
>   the container is still considered immutable, because the collection of
>   objects it contains cannot be changed. So, immutability is not
>   strictly the same as having an unchangeable value, it is more subtle.)
>   An object’s mutability is determined by its type; for instance,
>   numbers, strings and tuples are immutable, while dictionaries and
>   lists are mutable.

In your case `list` is mutable, `int` is immutable. Nothing weird.

More about [Data model](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: This isn't quite everything, though.  If OP did `d = [10 + x for x in range(3)]` then `d` and `self.d` would point to different objects.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, both `d` and `self.d` point to a mutable object. When you add ten to an element in the object you are modifying that mutable object. Because both `d` and `self.d` point to that object, they both "see" the result.

In the second example, you are reassigning d to point to a *different* immutable number, thus `d` and `self.d` point to two different things.

Note the difference: in one case they both point to the same value, which you are changing, and in the other case they point to two different values.