# In a Python `for` loop, is the iteration variable a reference? Can it be used to change the underlying data?

Tags: python

When using a `for` loop in Python to iterate over items in a list, will changing `item` (below) change the corresponding item in `items`?

```
for item in items:
    item += 1
```

Will each item in items be incremented or remain the same as before the loop?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Nope; does this [previous answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644) help at all?

Comment: I don't think it will chage the value (couldn't you try it?)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- Doesn't this depend critically on what type of object `item` actually is?  What if `items` are class instances with an appropriately defined `__iadd__`?

Comment: @mgilson: Ah, the question was edited. It was an assignment of `item = item + 1` before.

Comment: @DavidZwicker Because it may help others who don't have both Python (or either) installed. Also, if it was that easy why not answer and get some rep? :P

Comment: Martijn Pieters already answered your question, but peripherally related, this is the Pythonic way of doing it: `items = [x + 1 for x in items]`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, variables in Python are *not* pointers.

They refer to objects on a heap instead, and assigning to a variable doesn't change the referenced object, but the *variable*. Variables and objects are like labels tied to balloons; assignment reties the label to a different balloon instead.

See this [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644) to explore that idea of balloons and labels a bit more.

That said, some object *types* implement specific in-place addition behaviour. If the object is *mutable* (the balloon itself can change), then an in-place add *could* be interpreted as a mutation instead of an assignment.

So, for integers, `item += 1` is really the same as `item = item + 1` because integers are immutable. You *have* to create a new integer object and tie the `item` label to that new object.

Lists on the other hand, *are* mutable and `lst += [other, items]` is implemented as a `lst.__iadd__([other, items])` and that changes the `lst` balloon itself. An assignment still takes place, but it is a *reassigment* of the same object, as the `.__iadd__()` method simply returns `self` instead of a new object. We end up re-tying the label to the same balloon.

The loop simply gives you a reference to the next item in the list on each iteration. It does not let you change the original list itself (that's just another set of balloon labels); instead it gives you a new label to each of the items contained.

Comment: Most specifically, isn't it a mutation followed by an assignment?  You mutate the object in a function and then you make an assignment to whatever that function returns (which *should* be just the object itself, but doesn't have to be)? -- In other words, `i += something` is the same thing as `i = i.__iadd__(something)`

Comment: @mgilson: yes, `.__iadd__()` is expected to return `self` in that case.

Comment: Yes, expected to, but it doesn't have to.  I find it instructive to point that out as it explains very clearly how you can get different behavior using `+=` with mutable and immutable objects.

Answer (score 14):

Well, it really depends on the items.

Take the following case:

```
class test():
    pass

a = test()
a.value = 1

b = test()
b.value = 2

l = [a,b]

for item in l:
    item.value += 1

for item in l:
    print item.value

>>> 
2
3
```

and in this case:

```
l2 = [1,2,3]

for item in l2:
    item += 1

for item in l2:
    print item

>>> 
1
2
3
```

So as you can see, you need to understand the pointers as [Martijn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14814847/1561176) said.

Comment: You're right, it technically depends on the items (namely on the definition of `__iadd__`). But not in the way you show: Item assignment *always* works like that. What you show is that attribute assignment is different from local assignment, but that's an entirely different matter (though related and also important). -1

Comment: This is not correct; you are not assigning to a local variable, you are assigning to an attribute on another object. That is mutating the mutable object, not a local variable.

Comment: I never claimed otherwise, just showing that when iterating over a list in python you can do work on the items in certain situations, in other languages it is not allowed to manipulate the object/list you are iterating.

Comment: Okay, but that doesn't make your answer more relevant to the question. (Also note that you *aren't* mutating the list either way, you're just mutating objects which are referenced from several places, one of which happens to be a slot in a list.)

Comment: The OPs question is vague on the purpose or his desire. I simply know that the OP wants to iterate over a list, and is asking about 'in python' leading me to understand 'as opposed to other languages' so I provided two samples, one where iterating and changing works, and one where it doesn't. I hope it can guide the OP, or at least attempt to inform him in some way.