# Adding a column to the beginning of a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to add a new column to the beginning of a csv file, and I thought iterating through each row and just adding together a list containing my new column's content and the old list would work, and it does, but it only works inside the loop. Why is it doing that?

file:

```
column1 column2 column3
x1      y1      z1
x2      y2      z2
```

intended output:

```
0 column1 column2 column3
0 x1      y1      z1
0 x2      y2      z2
```

code:

```
import csv

x = open('C:/Documents and Settings/admin/Desktop/sample.csv')
y = csv.reader(x)
z = []
for row in y:
    z.append(row)
for n in z:
    n = ['0'] + n
    print(n)

for m in z:
    print(m)
```

what I get:

```
[0, column1, column2, column2]
[0, x1, y1, z1]
[0, x2, y2, z2]
[column1, column2, column2]
[x1, y1, z1]
[x2, y2, z2]
```

The zeros basically disappear outside that loop. Why?

Thanks!

Comment: Because of you do not change elements of `z`. You have to write like: `for i,n in enumerate(z): z[i] = ['0'] + n`

Comment: Maybe this help: [Do Python for loops work by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference)

Answer (score 1):

The particular "glitch" you're seeing is because of a result of scoping. Even though your first loop is setting `n` as `['0'] + n`, it only happens within the scope of that loop, without ever changing `z`.

What you could do is create a new list and appending the new `n` to that list:

```
new_list = []
for n in z:
    n = ['0'] + n
    new_list.append(n)

for m in new_list:
    print(m)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this if you change z when you change your row

```
import csv

x = open('C:/Documents and Settings/admin/Desktop/sample.csv')
y = csv.reader(x)
z = []
for row in y:
    z.append(['0'] + row)
print(z)

for m in z:
    print(m)
```