# Issue with concat in loop in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add some dummy variable columns to a list of databases in a for loop, however while the code works outside the loop as expected, it doesn't work when inside the loop. Here's a minimal working example- note when printing the df inside the loop it has the expected form, but then calling df1 and df2 outside the loop they don't have the additional columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':['a','b','c']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':['b','c','b']})
combine=[df1,df2]
for df in combine:
    df=pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['A'])],axis=1)
    print(df)
print(df1)
df1=pd.concat([df1,pd.get_dummies(df1['A'])],axis=1)
print(df1)

   A  a  b  c
0  a  1  0  0
1  b  0  1  0
2  c  0  0  1

   A  b  c
0  b  1  0
1  c  0  1
2  b  1  0

   A
0  a
1  b
2  c

   A  a  b  c
0  a  1  0  0
1  b  0  1  0
2  c  0  0  1
```

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you also post your desired outcome?

Comment: Your issue is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference). Use a different variable name either in iteration or in assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You experience no difference in `df1` or `df2` after the loop because within the loop you just change the reference `df` to point at brand new object, the result of

```
pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['A'])],axis=1)
```

The objects referenced by `df1` or `df2` are not getting changed themself.

Try to replace

```
df = pd.concat([df,pd.get_dummies(df['A'])],axis=1)
```

with

```
df[df['A'].unique()] = pd.get_dummies(df['A'])
```

and you will see the difference.