# Modifying dataFrames inside a list is not working

Tags: python, list, pandas, iteration

I have two `DataFrames` and I want to perform the same list of cleaning ops.
I realized I can merge into one, and to everything in one pass, but I am still curios why this method is not working

```
test_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [1, 8, 5, 6, 0],
    "B": [15, 49, 34, 44, 63]
})
test_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "A": [np.nan, 3, 6, 4, 9, 0],
    "B": [-100, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500]
})
```

Let's assume I want to only take the raws without `NaN`s: I tried

```
for df in [test_1, test_2]:
    df = df[pd.notnull(df["A"])]
```

but `test_2` is left untouched. On the other hand if I do:

```
test_2 = test_2[pd.notnull(test_2["A"])]
```

Now I the first raw went away.

Comment: You're assigning the output to `df`, the loop variable. The underlying dataframes are unaltered.

Comment: Related: [Do Python for loops work by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All these slicing/indexing operations create views/copies of the original dataframe and you then *reassign* `df` to these views/copies, meaning the originals are not touched at all.

**Option 1**
`dropna(...inplace=True)`
Try an in-place `dropna` call, this should modify the original object in-place

```
df_list = [test_1, test_2]
for df in df_list:
    df.dropna(subset=['A'], inplace=True)
```

Note, this is *one of the few times* that I will ever recommend an in-place modification, because of this use case in particular.

---

**Option 2**
`enumerate` with reassignment
Alternatively, you may re-assign to the list -

```
for i, df in enumerate(df_list):
    df_list[i] = df.dropna(subset=['A'])  # df_list[i] = df[df.A.notnull()]
```

Comment: I feel like there needs to be a canonical Q/A about "why isn't my DataFrame changed after operation x"

Comment: @pault yeah, this is one of those questions that keeps getting asked frequently, but under such unassuming titles that there's no way to find them in a reasonable amount of time! I'll bookmark this question and keep it in my list of targets from now on though :)

Comment: @pault Not specific to pandas but I think we have a canonical answer for this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference).

Comment: in the answer @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you say `view`. that's what I thought too, that the var was just a view on the underlying `df` and that i was modifying it

Answer (score 4):

You are modifying *copies* of the dataframes rather than the original dataframes.

One way to deal with this issue is to use a dictionary. As a convenience, you can use `pd.DataFrame.pipe` together with dictionary comprehensions to modify your dictionaries.

```
def remove_nulls(df):
    return df[df['A'].notnull()]

dfs = dict(enumerate([test_1, test_2]))
dfs = {k: v.pipe(remove_nulls) for k, v in dfs.items()}

print(dfs)

# {0:    A   B
#     0  1  15
#     1  8  49
#     2  5  34
#     3  6  44
#     4  0  63,
#  1:      A    B
#     1  3.0  100
#     2  6.0  200
#     3  4.0  300
#     4  9.0  400
#     5  0.0  500}
```

**Note**: In your result `dfs[1]['A']` remains `float`: this is because `np.nan` is considered `float` and we have not triggered a conversion to `int`.

Answer (score 3):

By using `pd.concat`

```
[x.reset_index(level=0,drop=True) for _, x in pd.concat([test_1,test_2],keys=[0,1]).dropna().groupby(level=0)]
Out[376]: 
[     A   B
 0  1.0  15
 1  8.0  49
 2  5.0  34
 3  6.0  44
 4  0.0  63,      A    B
 1  3.0  100
 2  6.0  200
 3  4.0  300
 4  9.0  400
 5  0.0  500]
```