# How to change a string in list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to delete leading comas in a sentence and I can't get why does this doesn't work

```py
text = ",greetings   friends"

text_l = text.split()
for word in text_l:
    if word.startswith(','):
        word = word[1:]
text = ' '.join(text_l)

>>> ,greetings friends
```

but this does.

```py
text = ",greetings   friends"

text_l = text.split()
for word in text_l:
    if word.startswith(','):
        indw = text_l.index(word)
        text_l[indw] = word[1:]
text = ' '.join(text_l)

>>> greetings friends
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list doesn't reflect variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change)

Comment: indeed, you do not need to split the string. Simply do this : `if text.startswith[',']: text = text[1:]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in Python do not work as pointer, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference) for a better explanation. 
In your first bit of code you are changing the value of the variable `word`, not the object that word refers to, therefore your loop is not changing anything in the original list of words.

The second codes does change the original list.

As a suggestion, a more pythonic way to do what you need:

```
original_text = ",greetings   friends"

text = ' '.join(part.lstrip(',') for part in original_text.split())
text = ' '.join(map(lambda part: part.lstrip(','), original_text.split()))  # If you want a colleague to ask you "what's that???" :)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code does not work because that only assigns a new value to the local variable `word`, *without:* changing the string in the list. Your second code works (as you noticed) but is inefficient, as you have to find the `index` of each word you want to strip. Instead, you can use `enumerate` to iterate words and indices at the same time, and also use `lstrip` instead of slicing the string.

```
text_l = text.split()
for i, word in enumerate(text_l):
    if word.startswith(','):
        text_l[i] = word.lstrip(",")
text = ' '.join(text_l)
```

Also, when using `lstrip` the `if` is not really necessary anymore, and we can compress the whole thing to a one-line generator expression within `' '.join(...)`:

```
text = ' '.join(word.lstrip(",") for word in text.split())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to delete a leading comma then lstrip is your desired command.

```
text = ",greetings   friends"

text_l = text.split()
text = []
for word in text_l:
    if word.startswith(','):
        word = word.lstrip(',')
    text.append(word)
text = ' '.join(text)
```

Output of text is:

```
greetings friends
```