# delete an element with a for loop in a geojson file

Tags: python, python-3.x, geojson

for a .geojson lambda file :

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      { "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
          },
          "properties": {
            "label": "value0",
             ...
          }
        },
       { "type": "Feature",
         "geometry": {..
```

I would like to delete "Point" and "Polygon" and even "MultiPolygon" type of structures which have a key `'label'` in `properties`.

```
   import json

   file = open('file.geojson', 'r')
   data = json.load(file)
   
   for k in data['features']:
       if 'label' in k['properties']:
           print('ok') #displays the right number of structure, so the loop works
           del k #doesn't work
           #data['features'].remove(k) works but delete only a part of elements in the file..
           print('okk') #displays so del doesn't work
   
   data_srt = open('file.geojson', 'w')
   data_srt.write(json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2))
   data_srt.close()
```

These solutions don't work, why ? Thank you very much.

Comment: They don't work because the syntax of the code is wrong due to unmatched quotes.

Comment: I edited, obviously my problem remains the same.

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding. What exactly is the problem? You said it doesn't work, would you please expand on that? What was wrong with `data['features'].remove(k)`?

Comment: With `del k` my file is exactly the same in output and with `data['features'].remove(k)` only a part of the structures that have a key `label` are deleted... I tried with a file that have only two structures that both have a key `label`, only the first one is delete (the first k in fact).

Comment: Yes `print('ok')` works.

Comment: I usually use `print()` statements to debug any code that I am working with, have you tried `print(data)` just to see what the dictionary looks like, to make sure that the format is consistent?

Comment: I am having a difficult time recreating this problem. For me, `data["features"].remove(k)` removes all structures with a `'label'` key.

Comment: Yes, I tried `print(data)`, look like good. I even tried with a standard .geojson file like [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) by adding in each `properties` a `label` key, It doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    l.remove(i)

print(l) # Prints '[2]'
```

During the first iteration `i == l[0]`. `l.remove(i)` would then be the same as `l.remove(l[0])`. During the second iteration, `i == l[1]`. At this point, though, `l == [2, 3]`, because `l[0]` was removed. So, in the second iteration, `l.remove(i)` is the same as `l.remove(l[1])`. After this is executed, `l == [2]`. If the loop tries to continue to a third iteration, `i == l[2]`. However, now that `l == [2]`, `len(l) == 1` so `l[2]` is out of bounds. Because of this, the `for` loop stops now, even though `l` is not empty. This is essentially the same problem that you are experiencing.

To fix this:

```
i = len(l) - 1
while i >= 0:
    l.remove(l[i])
    i -= 1
```

Iterating over a list backwards like this avoids the out-of-bounds problem that was encountered before.

To apply this concept in your situation, **this is the solution**:

```
i = len(data["features"]) - 1
while i >= 0:
    if "label" in data["features"][i]["properties"]:
        data["features"].pop(i)
    i -= 1
```

I just came up with a new, **better solution** (it uses the `reversed()` function):

```
for k in reversed(data["features"]):
    if "label" in k["properties"]:
        data["features"].remove(k)
```

This uses the same concept of backwards-iterating, but the `reversed()` function takes care of that for you.

The reason why the `del` statement had no functionality for you is caused by a more complex concept. I'll will do my best to explain (here is another answer that sort of helps explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14814847/13911868).

When iterating through a list, or any container, in a `for` loop, like this:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in l:
    del i
```

The `i` variable is a deep **copy** of an item in the `l`, **not a reference**. That being the case, `del i` would delete the copied item only, not deleting the original item from `l`.

On the other hand, in this example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(l)):
    del l[i]
```

`del l[i]` will delete the original item in `l` because `l[i]` returns that **original** object, **not a copy**.

In this example, though, you will encounter the same out-of-bounds problem as before, so a working **solution using the `del`** statement would be:

```
for k in reversed(range(len(data["features"]))):
    if "label" in data["features"][k]["properties"]:
        del data["features"][k]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanations ! And I still don't understand why `del` doesn't work... would you know?

Comment: @Tim    I just added to my answer to include an explanation about the `del` statement in your situation.