# python for loop modifying elements

Tags: python, for-loop, reference

As explained in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14814771/do-python-for-loops-work-by-reference) for loops in python do not work by reference. Therefore, a program like that

```
a=[1,2,3]
for el in a:
    el += 1
print(a)
```

will not modify a.

In c++ there is instead the possibility to have for loops either by copy or reference. For instance, the following c++ code modifies the contents of the array a

```
std::array<int, 3> a{1, 2, 3};
for auto& el : a
    el += 1;
```

Is there a way to implement a syntax in python that achieve the same as the c++ loop above?

Edit: to be more precise, I am looking forward to a syntax such that, analogous to the c++ example, I have inside the loop a sort-of-reference to the elements of a.

Comment: Something like:   `for i,v in enumerate(a):  a[i] +=  1`  ?

Comment: @Ank well, that would certainly work. But ```v``` has, again, a value semantic and I cannot use  it to update a.

Comment: AFAIK you cannot do it with `v` then in python. You will have to do via indexes or the elements inside list themselves have to be mutable to do it via `v`. Both languages are different in this regard. You can check this [post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/341179/why-does-python-only-make-a-copy-of-the-individual-element-when-iterating-a-list) as well for more info.

Answer (score 1):

```
a=[1,2,3]
for i, el in enumerate(a):
    a[i] += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you do this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(a)):
   temp = a[i]
   a.pop(i)
   a.insert(i, temp+1)
```

You're simply replacing the elements with newer values.

Comment: if you are using `range(len(a))`, why not just do `a[i] += 1` instead of popping and inserting new values

Answer (score 0):

This is because "el" is a copy of each element in the list

You can do this to edit the list

```
a=[1,2,3]
for el in range(len(a)):
    a[el] += 1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the elements of the list are integers which are immutable (unchangable). A workaround would be to replace them with something that was, like a (nested) `list`:

```
a = [[1], [2], [3]]
for el in a:
    el[0] += 1
print(a)  # -> [[2], [3], [4]]
```

However since `a` itself *is* mutable, you could simply to this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for i in range(len(a)):
    a[i] += 1
print(a)  # -> [2, 3, 4]
```