# failed to add 1 to an integer list using for loop

Tags: python, list

As a new python learner, I'm quite confused about why the `list_2` output isn't`[2,4,6,8,10]`

```
list_1=[[1,3],[3,4],[5,8]]
for x in list_1:
    x[0]=1
print(list_1)

list_2=[1,3,5,7,9]
for x in list_2:
    x=x+1
print(list_2)
```

Output

```
[[1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 8]]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Comment: you are changing the number not assigning it back to the list

Comment: Please see https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1/names1.html and specifically page 18.

Comment: how to assign the new value to the list element without using list comprehension

Comment: There are some good answers on [Do Python for loops work by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14814771/5358968)

Comment: Thank you guys so much. I will look into the reference.

Comment: @Abhishek they aren't *changing the number*, they are creating *new numbers*

Comment: One way You could do it with a list compression is `for i, x in enumerate(list_2): list2[i] = x+1`