# Why do Python variables take a new address (id) every time they're modified?

Tags: python

Just wondering what the logic behind this one is? On the surface it seems kind of inefficient, that every time you do something simple like "x=x+1" that it has to take a new address and discard the old one.

Answer (score 8):

The Python variable (called an identifier or name, in Python) is a reference to a value. The `id()` function says something for that value, not the name.

Many values are not mutable; integers, strings, floats all do *not* change in place. When you add `1` to another integer, you return a *new* integer that then replaces the reference to the old value.

You can look at Python names as labels, tied to values. If you imagine values as balloons, you are *retying* the label a new balloon each time you assign to that name. If there are no other labels attached to a balloon anymore, it simply drifts away in the wind, never to be seen again. The `id()` function gives you a unique number for that balloon.

See this [previous answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644) where I talk a little bit more about that idea of values-as-balloons.

This may seem inefficient. For many *often used* and *small* values, Python actually uses a process called interning, where it will cache a stash of these values for re-use. `None` is such a value, as are small integers and the empty tuple (`()`). You can use the [`intern()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#intern) function to do the same with strings you expect to use a lot.

But note that values are only cleaned up when their reference count (the number of 'labels') drops to 0. Loads of values are reused all over the place all the time, especially those interned integers and singletons.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. Yeah this seems inefficient to me because I'm much more familiar with strongly typed compiled languages. So for an interpreted language with dynamic typing this is not such a bad way to do things.. Is that what it boils down to?

Comment: @user2076369: That's what it boils down to, yes.

Answer (score 2):

Because the basic types are immutable, so every time you modify it, it needs to be instantiated again

...which is perfectly fine, especially for [thread-safe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-safe) functions

Comment: Sorry. All of the above answers here are just telling me "what" happens (which I know, it has to be that way if those variables are immutable). but I'm interested in why? This way of doing thing just seems inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the "thread safe" aspect of this way of doing things. That was something I hadn't previously considered.

Answer (score 2):

The `=` operator doesn't modify an object, it assigns the name to a completely different object, which may or may not already have an id.

For your example, integers are immutable; there's no way to add something to one and keep the same id.

And, in fact, small integers are interned at least in cPython, so if you do:

```
x = 1
y = 2
x = x + 1
```

Then `x` and `y` may have the same id.

Answer (score 1):

In python "primitive" types like ints and strings are immutable, which means they can not be modified.

Python is actually quite efficient, because, as **@Wooble** commented, «*Very short strings and small integers are interned.*»: if two variables reference the same (*small*) immutable value their id is the same (reducing duplicated immutables).

```
>>> a = 42
>>> b = 5
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
>>> b += 37
>>> id(a) == id(b)
True
```

The reason behind the use of immutable types is a safe approach to the concurrent access on those values.

At the end of the day it depends on a design choice.

Depending on your needs you can take more advantage of an implementation instead of another.
For instance, a different philosophy can be found in a somewhat similar language, Ruby, where those types that in Python are immutable, are not.

Comment: "usually" is a bit overstated. Very short strings and small integers are interned.

Comment: Yes I thought it was only a very limited range of integers that interned like that. Which makes sense, address by value is easy of a small set but not so much on a large one.

Answer (score 1):

To be accurate, assignment `x=x+1` doesn't modify the object that `x` is referencing, it just lets the x point to another object whose value is `x+1`.

To understand the logic behind, one needs to understand the difference between [value semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_semantics) and reference semantics.

An object with value semantics means only its value matters, not its identity. While an object with reference semantics focuses on its identity(in Python, identity can be returned from `id(obj)`).

Typically, value semantics implies immutability of the object. Or conversely, if an object is mutable(i.e. in-place change), that means it has reference semantics.

Let's briefly explain the rationale behind this immutability.

Objects with reference semantics can be changed **in-place** without losing their original addresses/identities. This makes sense in that it's the identity of an object with reference semantics that makes itself distinguishable from other objects.

In contrast, an object with value-semantics should never change itself.

First, this is possible and reasonable in theory. Since only the value(not its identity) is significant, when a change is needed, it's safe to swap it to another identity with different value. This is called [referential transparency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_transparency_%28computer_science%29). Be noted that this is impossible for the objects with reference semantics.

Secondly, this is beneficial in practice. As the OP thought, it seems inefficient to discard the old objects each time when it's changed , but most time it's more efficient than not. For one thing, Python(or any other language) has intern/cache scheme to make less objects to be created. What's more, if objects of value-semantics were designed to be mutable, it would take much more space in most cases.

For example, Date has a value semantics. If it's designed to be mutable, any method that returning a date from internal field will exposes the handle to outside world, which is risky(e.g. outside can directly modify this internal field without resorting to public interface). Similarly, if one passes any date object by reference to some function/method, this object could be modified in that function/method, which may be not as expected. To avoid these kinds of side-effect, one has to do [defensive programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming): instead of directly returning the inner date field, he returns a clone of it; instead of passing by reference, he passes by value which means extra copies are made. As one could imagine, there are more chances to create more objects than necessary. What's worse, code becomes more complicated with these extra cloning.

In a word, immutability enforces the value-semantics, it usually involves less object creation, has less side-effects and less hassles, and is more test-friendly. Besides, immutable objects are inherently thread-safe, which means less locks and better efficiency in multithreading environment.

That's the reason why basic data types of value-semantics like number, string, date, time are all immutable(well, string in C++ is an exception, that's why there're so many `const string&` stuffs to avoid string being modified unexpectedly). As a lesson, Java made mistakes on designing value-semantic class `Date`, `Point`, `Rectangle`, `Dimension` as mutable.

As we know, objects in OOP have three characteristics: state, behavior and identity. Objects with value semantics are not typical *objects* in that their identities do not matter at all. Usually they are *passive*, and mostly used to describe other *real*, *active* objects(i.e. those with reference semantics). This is a good hint to distinguish between value semantics and reference semantics.