# Python List assignment error

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings stored in `wk`

I run the following code.

```
n_wk=wk
for i in range(10):
    if some condition:
       n_wk[i]='new'
```

I wanted to reserve the `wk` values. But, the `wk` is also getting changed along with `n_wk`. can anyone point out the error in this?

Comment: `n_wk` and `wk` are actually the same list this way. You need to explicitly copy the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a *copy* of `wk`:

```
n_wk = list(wk)
```

or use:

```
n_wk = wk[:]
```

both of which copy the indices over to a new list.

Comment: Because assignment doesn't always copy. Only the basic types are copied, lists, dictionaries and other objects are copied by reference, so they point to the same object. The above will also only work on lists and similar structures, consider this for more complex objects: http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: assignment *never* copies. Usually you *reassign* a new value.

Comment: >>> a = 5
>>> b = a
>>> a = 4
>>> b
5
disagrees with you.

Comment: @searcoding: Because you assigned the same list to two names; that doesn't create a copy. You were modifying *the same list*.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: that is normal assignment. Python names are *not* pointers to a memory slot. Python variables instead are like labels tied to values. Imagine values as balloons instead. You tied `a` and `b` to the same balloon (value), but then you retied the `a` label to a *new* balloon with the int value 4.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: See [Python list doesn't reflect variable change, new to python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/12080644#12080644)

Comment: Yes, but the effect is the same. It always assigns the value of the variable, but in the case of a list, dict, etc. the value is a reference to the object, whereas in the case of a basic type it's the value itself. So using assignment on basic values is like making copies of it, even if the internals are different.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: No, they are *always* references. There is no difference between assigning a mutable and an immutable type. Only the *types* themselves differ.

Comment: @StjepanBakrac: You are confusing changing the value with the name pointing to the value.