# Creating Python variables that are independent of each other

Tags: python, list

If I have this Python code:

```
foo = [3, 5, 9]
bar = foo
bar.append(9)
print(foo)
```

It returns

```
[3, 5, 9, 9]
```

Which surely means that when I appended `9` to `bar`, it also affected `foo`. How do I make the variable `bar` equal to `foo`, but so that when I edit `bar`, it does not effect `foo`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are altering a mutable value, so you need to make an explicit copy:

```
bar = list(foo)
```

or

```
bar = foo[:]
```

When assigning to a name in Python, all you do is store a *reference* to the value. Without creating a copy of the list, both `foo` and `bar` referred to the same list.

For non-mutable values this is not a problem; you replace a reference to, say, a string to point to a different value instead.

But lists (and `dict` and `set` and instances of most classes) are mutable. You didn't change `foo`, you changed the *value `foo` refers to*. You did `foo.append(9)`, which Python sees as:

- Find the value `foo` refers to.
- Find the attribute `.append` on that value. This returns a method on a list instance.
- Call the method, passing in the value `9`. This alters the list.

Python names themselves are nothing more than labels, pointing to actual values. You could see the values as balloons, the names as little paper tags, and assignment is the act of tying the labels to the balloons. `bar = foo` created a second paper tag, that was tied to the *exact same balloon*.

See this [older answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change-new-to-python/12080644#12080644) where I push the balloon metaphor around some more.

Comment: +1, Beat me to it. I'm personally more of a fan of using `list()`, as it works with any iterable and I feel it is more readable (which is backed up by the number of questions on SO asking what `[:]` does).

Comment: Why does this Python code on ideone: http://ideone.com/QIjOsD not produce the expected result (three 1's, not four)? Have I done something wrong?

Comment: @Lewis: nested lists. You only copied the *outer* list. The outer list is nothing but a dynamic series of paper tags, numbered sequentially. And to these numbered tags are more strings to more values, each another list. Copying the outer list just copied over the labels, including new strings to whatever they were tied to. Use the `copy` module to create a deep copy (`b = copy.deepcopy(a)`), or use a list comprehension: `b = [elem[:] for elem in a]`. The list comprehension creates shallow copies of each contained list, generating a new outer list with those shallow copies as elements.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, I wrote the comment while you were editing yours :)

Answer (score 2):

You make a copy:

```
bar = foo[:]  #copy of foo
bar.append(9)
```

This has to do with how python deals with assignment.  Assignment says **"take the object on the right and store it under the name on the left in the local namespace"**.  So, in your case, you have foo and bar referencing the same object which is why appending to one also effects the other.

Things can get a little more interesting with immutable objects when using operators which *usually* operate on the object in place (e.g. `+=`).  See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376509/when-is-i-x-different-from-i-i-x-in-python/15376520#15376520) for example and a lot more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

When creating copies of the original while removing all references to it (so you can't edit the original), you use deep copy.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

```
import copy
bar = copy.deepcopy(foo)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy):

```
>>> from copy import deepcopy
>>> foo = [3, 5, 9]
>>> bar = deepcopy(foo)
>>> bar.append(9)
>>> print(foo)
[3, 5, 9]
>>> print bar
[3, 5, 9, 9]
```