# How can I assign by value in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I understand that, due to the way Python works `x = []; y = x; x.append(1); y` will print `[1]`. However, the reverse, say,

```
z = [1,2]
temp = z
temp[1] = 3
z,temp
```

will print `([1,3],[1,3])`. If I understand correctly, both `z` and `temp` point to the same list, so changing one will change the other, seeing as lists are mutable. How can I prevent this from happening? Namely, I want to make a for loop that will copy `z` into `temp`, change it in different ways, and push it onto a queue. For that to work, `z` must always contain the base array, therefore I need that changing `temp` doesn't change `z`.

EDIT: I tried changing z into a tuple so that `z=z,`, then calling `z[0]` instead of `z`. Still this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Technically, Python is only pass-by-value - the difference you are seeing is more between mutable and immutable types. As for your question: You could create a copy of the list with e.g. `newlist = oldlist[:]`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating Python variables that are independent of each other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16362617/creating-python-variables-that-are-independent-of-each-other)

Comment: @miku No, mutability has nothing to do with assignment just creating another reference. After `a = b`, `a is b` is *always* true, no matter the types involved. The only thing mutability impacts is how easy it is to stumble over this fact.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Copying a list is easy ... Just slice it:

```
temp = z[:]
```

This will create a shallow copy -- mutations to elements in the list will show up in the elements in `z`, but not changes to `temp` directly.

---

For more general purposes, python has a `copy` module that you can use:

```
temp = copy.copy(z)
```

Or, possibly:

```
temp = copy.deepcopy(z)
```

Comment: In this specific case, I'm actually working with a POD class with 3 lists. The `copy` module works like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Why not make `temp` a *copy* of `z`:

```
>>> z = [1, 2]
>>> temp = z[:]
>>> temp[1] = 3
>>> z
[1, 2]
>>> temp
[1, 3]
>>>
```

`[:]` easily makes a shallow copy of a list.

However, you might also be interested in [`copy.copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.copy) and [`copy.deepcopy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy), both of which come from Python's [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#module-copy) module.

Comment: In this specific case, I'm actually working with a POD class with 3 lists. The copy module works like a charm. Thanks.