# Why are my instances changing?

Tags: python, class, oop

I'm making a class of polynomial objects, represented by dictionaries:

> 3*x^2+x+2 == {2:3, 1:1, 0:2}

This is the part of my code that's relevant for the question:

```
class Sparse_polynomial():
    def __init__(self, coeffs_dict):
        self.coeffs_dict = coeffs_dict


    def __repr__(self):
        terms = [" + ("+str(self.coeffs_dict[k])+"*x^" + str(k)+")" \
                 for k in sorted(self.coeffs_dict.keys(), reverse=True)]
        terms = "".join(terms)
        return terms[3:]  

    def __neg__(self):
        neg_pol= self.coeffs_dict
        for key in self.coeffs_dict:
            neg_pol[key]= -self.coeffs_dict[key]
        return Sparse_polynomial(neg_pol)
```

Whenever I try to use the `__neg__` method, the original object changes.  For example:

```
>>> p1= Sparse_polynomial({1:3,5:1})
>>> p1
(1*x^5) + (3*x^1)
>>> -p1
(-1*x^5) + (-3*x^1)
>>> p1
(-1*x^5) + (-3*x^1)
>>>
```

I really can't understand why the original `p1` changes. I made no direct changes to it, only accessed its fields.

Can anyone clarify so I can fix this?

Comment: new_dict = dict(old_dict) will copy it for you, you want a copy not reference

Answer (score 2):

> I made no direct changes to it, only accessed it's field.

That's not true: look at your code ...

```
def __neg__(self):
    neg_pol= self.coeffs_dict
    for key in self.coeffs_dict:
        neg_pol[key]= -self.coeffs_dict[key]
```

You grabbed a reference to the coefficients dictionary and negated every member.  This is *not* a copy; it's a reference to the original.

If you're trying to return a separate dictionary, then use one of the several copy methods available.  A popular one is `copy` from the class itself:

```
neg_pol = self.coeffs_dict.copy()
```

To check the "handle" of an item, use the `id` method.  For instance:

```
print id(self.coeffs_dict), id(neg_pol)
```

This shows readily that the two variable names refer to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

As the others pointed out the:

```
neg_pol = self.coeffs_dict
```

doesn't create a new dict, `neg_pol` will be just another reference for the **same dictionary** and any changes (like `neg_pol[key] = -self.coeffs_dict[key]`) will be visible for both variables.

Personally I prefer dict-comprehensions to create new dicts instead of just using `copy`:

```
class Sparse_polynomial():

    # ... your other stuff

    def __neg__(self):
        return Sparse_polynomial({key: -value for key, value in self.coeffs_dict.items()})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a copy, just a reference to the original dictionary:

```
neg_pol = self.coeffs_dict
```

You want a copy, so you can mutate it without messing with the original:

```
neg_pol = self.coeffs_dict.copy()
```

You may want to check "[How can I assign by value in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300366/how-can-i-assign-by-value-in-python)" for clues on how to copy other mutable objects - Python is not very consistent on how to copy builtins, for example the `list` type has no `copy` method and most people use slicing notation in order to copy a list:

```
new_list = old_list[:]
```

As MSeifert suggested, dict comprehensions are a good way to generate a mutated copy:

```
>>> original_dict = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
>>> square_dict = {k + "²": v * 2 for k, v in original_dict.items()} 
>>> double_dict
{'a²': 4, 'b²': 9}
>>> original_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: A good question is half the answer, so you are very welcome!