# Is there a way for a change in a variable in a list to be reflected in the list?

Tags: python, list, variables

For Example:

```
Variable = 1
List = [0, Variable, 2, 3]
Variable = 5
print(List)
```

output is [0,1,2,3]. Is there a way to get [0,5,2,3] other than redefining the list? Also, can it be done in reverse (i.e. List[1] = 5, making Variable == 5)?

Comment: Helpful reading: [Python Names and Values](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html) from Ned Batchelder

Comment: Not directly. Would a dict work here?

Comment: The list doesn't contain a variable. It contains the same *value* that was *referenced* by the variable at the time the list was created.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list doesn't reflect variable change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12080552/python-list-doesnt-reflect-variable-change)

Comment: See also [Is it possible to overload Python assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11024646/2173773)

Answer (score 4):

Not directly. The list isn't going to know about the reassignment and there isn't any way to intercept the reassignment and do some meta programming. (*Except wrong, see note). If `Variable` is a container, you can update its contents and both would see. It could be a `dict` or a `list` for instance. But a class is a convenient way to do it. In this easy example, all users have to know to use `variable.val` but you could also put the time into implementing all of the dunder methods to abstract that away.

```
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

variable = Variable(1)
my_list = [0, variable, 2, 3]
variable.val += 1
my_list[1].val += 1
print(variable.val)
```

*Note from the comments in the original question that assignment can be overridden, but its messy. This method is more clear to me, but if you like magic, then https://stackoverflow.com/a/52438651/642070

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to understand why your code will not work the way it's supposed to. First of all you declared the variable `Variable` and initialized it as 1. You then used it in a list. Now your list contains the values of 0, Variable, 2, 3 which is the same as the list containing the values of 0, 1, 2, 3. Now you updated the variable called `Variable` and you changed it to 5. You see, you updated the variable but not the list... The list has no use of a variable, so it extracted the data it needed from that variable which was the number one... So it was as if you never even put a variable called `Variable`, it was as if you just put the number one... So when you updated variable, the list was just looking at it like, "That package's not for me, I already got mine!". Now enough gibberish... down to the solution! First after creating the list, if you know you want to update that particular value, you store it in a variable:

```
Variable = 1
List = [0, Variable, 2, 3]
Variable = List[1]
```

Now the list sees that you are using this value, and updates along with it... So if you update it you are not updating the variable but are updating a value in the list:

```
Variable = 1
List = [0, Variable, 2, 3]
Variable = List[1]
Variable = 5
```

So if you tell it to print the list:

```
print(List)
```

Your result is "[0, 5, 2, 3]"!
Hope this helped!

Comment: The result I'm seeing is [0, 1, 2, 3] (unupdated), using Python 3.10.

Answer (score 0):

Python variable hold the reference of values.

Variable = 1
List = [0, Variable, 2, 3]

In your list you pass the Variable reference not value itself.

## only way to reflect

List[1] = Variable