# Set variables stored in a list to None with a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I store variables in a list to access them later with a for loop.
My desire is to set some of the *variables not just the list's entries* to `None`

```
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(3,2)
b = np.random.rand(3,2)
c = np.random.rand(3,2)

data_lists = [a,b,c]


data_lists[:] = [None]
```

won't work. Does anyone know a pythonic way to do it without explicitly writing `a = None` and so on?

Comment: what is the expected output? you can't reference back the variable names

Comment: "I store variables in a list to access them later with a for loop." - then you should probably be using a list in the first place, not some unrelated variables..

Comment: Variables aren't stored in the list; values are. Storing different values in the list has no effect on the values still referenced by `a` et al. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Integers are immutable setting new values in a list only rewrites the references, so the variables are not affected. In theory, you could do it with mutable objects (for example lists inside of your list)

Comment: Also, does this answer your question? [Is there a way for a change in a variable in a list to be reflected in the list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63566948/is-there-a-way-for-a-change-in-a-variable-in-a-list-to-be-reflected-in-the-list)

Comment: While it is possible to do something like this, I would suggest to rethink thoroughly why do you need to that, and perhaps if there are better alternatives (you probably need to use a different data structure).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could do `a = b = c = None`, then recreate `data_lists` by doing `data_lists = [a, b, c]` again. You can't set a variable to `None` implicitly. Hope this helps